# Blank search should show all results

Tags: views, 8, search

I remember that, in previous versions of the Search API and Search API Solr, by default not entering any search term would return the entire list of items.

I have tried with new empty Drupal 8.5.1 using Search API and Search API Solr, using the default configuration, with MariaDB and Postgresql, using the default view pages /search/content and /solr-search/content, but it shows an empty list and the message *Please enter some keywords to search.* message.

Does somebody know how to change it to the previous behavior to get again the whole list of elements when no search terms are used?

Comment: Remove the "required" status on the exposed filter?

Comment: I have the same issue,I removed the required status of the exposed filter,but still I get no results.Any help on this?

Answer (score 3):

After trying everything that I could figure out, I have uninstalled the module, deleting all the views and installing it again and it works. No idea about what was happening sorry, but it work.

---

Finally thanks for some help I could understand what was happening :D The Filter Criteria Fulltext search was a Required, if you remove the checkbox then you will get the full list of items by default.